# how to auto scroll down in div on content added?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, chat

I am developing a chat program using jquery, php and ajax. and my problem is that when user puts msgs and when the chat box is overflowed it should auto scroll down when new msg enter and chat box overflowed. What I tried to achieve is this.

**CODE**

```
 $.ajaxSetup ({
  cache: false
 });
$(document).ready(function(e) {


setInterval (function() {
    $('.main').load('display_messages.php');
},1000)

$(function() {
    //Function for press Return button
    $('#newMessageContent').keypress(function(e) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 || !event.keyCode == all  ) {
                setTimeout (function() {
                    $('.main').load('display_messages.php');
                    setTimeout (function() {
                        $('.main p:last').addClass('animated fadeIn');
                    },20)
                },50);
            //$('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
        }
    });
    // Functions for click button
    $('#newMessageSend').click(function() {
        setTimeout (function() {
                $('.main').load('display_messages.php');
                setTimeout (function() {
                    $('.main p:last').addClass('animated fadeIn');
                },20)
        },50);
        //$('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    });




    var chckIt = setInterval(function(){
         $('.main').one('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
             setTimeout(function() {
                $('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
             },500);
         })
    },1000)

    $('.main').on('scroll',function(){
        if ( $('.main').scrollTop() === 0 ){
        clearInterval(chckIt);
        }
    });

 });    

});
```

it has some bugs. it will auto scroll down but it repeat itself again and again and not stoping, and you cant scroll up to see older msgs if u want.

so then I used this function `$('.main').on('scroll',function(){
            if ( $('.main').scrollTop() === 0 ){
            clearInterval(chckIt);
            }
        });` to control it but its useless.

here is html.

**code**

```
        <div class="chatBox">
    <div class="chatlogo">
            <embed src="test2.swf" play="true" class="vid2" loop="true" width="180" height="50" salign="C" scale="ShowAll" id="vid_2" quality="High" wmode="transparent" name="vid_2" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      </div>
        <div class="user">

        <form name="signIn" id="signInForm" action="signout_delete_content.php" method="post" onSubmit="return false">
            <span class="error animated">Invalid uername</span>
            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" size="13px" onClick='document.username.value = "" '>
            <input type="submit" id="signIn" value="SING IN">
        </form>
            <span class="welcome"></span>
            <input type="button" id="signOut" value="SIGN OUT" onclick="window.location.reload();">
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <p>Admistrator: Hello msgs here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="messageBox">
            <form name="messageBoxSignInForm" id="messageBoxSignInForm" onSubmit="return false">
            <input type="submit" id="messageBoxSignIn" value="Sign In to Enter Chat">
            </form>
          <form name="newMessage" class="newMessage" action="" onSubmit="return false">
            <textarea name="newMessageContent" id="newMessageContent" placeholder="Enter your message here.">Enter your message here</textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="newMessageSend" value="Send">

          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600732/add-text-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-or-another-element-emulating-chat-console/24601102#24601102) If you don't find it useful, build a simple  [jBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) 'cause it would be easier to test your code.

Comment: it also has php coding , so it cant be used in jsfiddle

Comment: You can emulate adding content; 'cause this `...how to auto scroll down in div` has nothing to do with PHP :)

Comment: the php file is loaded through ajax, didnt you see in code?

Comment: Well, I see the code... this `$('.main').load('display_messages.php')` could be emulated with `somebuttoon.onclick = function() { populate that div with some text` } and that's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scroll up because you keep triggering load('display_message.php'), which will trigger 'DOMSubtreeModified' event. So, you can't rely on 'DOMSubtreeModified' and have to check for a new message by other means. For example, you may count the number of messages for each 'display_message.php' and check for difference.

```
var old = 0, new = 0;
$('#newMessageSend').click(function() {
    setTimeout (function() {
            $('.main').load('display_messages.php', chckIt);
            setTimeout (function() {
                $('.main p:last').addClass('animated fadeIn');
            },20)
    },50);
    //$('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
});


var chckIt = function(){
    new = $('.main').children().length;
         if (new > old)
         {
             old = new;
             setTimeout(function() {
                $('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
             },500);
         }
     };
```

Comment: there is syntax error on this line `var old = 0, new = 0;`

Comment: its working , but i want it to show msgs on both browsers and also scroll down on both browsers between 2 users. how to do that? did you test that?

Comment: Without this code, does it show messages on 2 browsers?

Comment: This may involve with you server side. How do you do it on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You were right,my previous answer doesn't works..

```
$('.messageBox').scrollTop($('.messageBox')[0].scrollHeight)
```

this works well:

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4TN/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57225/discussion-between-mr-beginner-and-nsthethunderbolt).

Comment: keep this method running separately, and whenever a new message comes add it to the message box.. and take out this timeout function to some place open.. don't mix it with other functions. OR else if you are using HTML5 use SSE events for this purpose.

Comment: It's because you keep loading elements in .main via load function, which will trigger DOMSubtreeModified.

Comment: so what is the solution?