# Write paragraph in a bottom of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to build something like chat, I want that what the user input inside the text-area will show up in the bottom of a specific div, and the older message above him.

I tried some stuff but it didn't work out.

```
#chatlog {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    max-height: 500px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

this is the html code:

```
<div class="chat-log-wrapper">
    <div id="chatlog"></div>
</div>

<div class="input-text">
    <div class="area">
        <textarea rows="2" type="text" id="message_input">
        </textarea>
        <button id="send-message">send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript (recieves message from other client and append it):

```
socketio.on("message_to_client", function (data) {
    $('#chatlog').append("<p>"+data["message"]+"</p>")
});
```

It seems that the display:table-cell is ruining the overflow-y.

Comment: What did you try, and why did it not work?>

Comment: i tried the above code, but the div is continue growing and the scroll bar is not activated

Comment: That's just CSS. Where is your HTML and Javascript?

Comment: Check this answer [Add text to the bottom of a div - emulating chat console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600732/add-text-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-or-another-element-emulating-chat-console/24601102#24601102)

Comment: This is for node, right? A jsfiddle or codepen would be helpful.

Comment: thanks @hex494D49 , i didn't find that on my search, sorry about that.
working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as well take a look at `display:flex;` and `flex-direction:column-reverse;`.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bytgq)**

Some more info here in a tutorial : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

and at W3C : (latest draft?) http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by setting `display:table-cell` and `width` on the `wrapper` instead of the current `div`:

```
.chat-log-wrapper{
    display:table-cell;
    width:1400px;
}

#chatlog {
    //display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    //max-height: 500px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q7zb5Lv5/